# Mostrar datos de una matriz en forma de caracteres

Tags: java

Llevo unos cuantos días dándole vueltas al siguiente problema: Tengo una matriz cuadrada de n por n elementos creados de forma aleatoria mediante math random

```js
public static void creaMatriz (int matriz [][],int d){
  for (int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){  
   for (int j=0;j<tablero[0].length;j++){  
    System.out.print ("["+tablero[i][j]+"]"+" ");
   }
   System.out.println("");
  }
 }
```

Dentro des mismo programa, tengo un método que da valores numéricos a la matriz de forma aleatoria (mediante math.random) la duda que tengo es como podría sacar por pantalla símbolos ('!','?'...) en vez de los números obtenidos de forma aleatoria, osea, si tuviese que aparecer un '1', en vez de ese número aparezca un '?', si fuese un '2' aparezca un '!'.

Una de las ideas que tuve fue, a la hora de crear la matriz con los números aleatorios, que esta se 'poblase' con caracteres ascii, pero entonces ya estoy cambiando la funcionalidad del programa, ya que este debe operar con integers y, únicamente a la hora de imprimir por pantalla mostrar caracteres (como los mencionados '?', '@'... y no los números enteros. Seguro que es mucho más sencillo que las ideas que he tenido pero no logro dar con ello.

```html
 public static void cambiaSim (int tablero[][]){
  char[] simbolos={'@','?','#','*','~','.','ç','/','$'};
  char [][]tableroA= new char[9][9];
  
  for (int i=0;i<tablero.length;i++){
   for (int j=0;j<tablero[0].length;j++){
    tableroA[i][j]=simbolos[(int)(Math.random()*9)];
    System.out.println(tableroA[i][j]+" ");
   }
   System.out.println(" ");
  }
```

También he intentado recorrer la matriz y cambiar el tipo de dato asignandole un char, pero no consigo imprimirlo corectamente por pantalla:

```html
public static void cambiaTablero (int tablero [][]){
  
  for (int i=0;i<tablero.length;i++){

   for (int j=0;j<tablero[0].length;j++){ 
    
   
    if (tablero[i][j]==0){
     (tablero[i][j])=((char)('*')); 
    }else if (tablero[i][j]==1){
     (tablero[i][j])=((char)('#'));
    }else if (tablero[i][j]==3){
     (tablero[i][j])=((char)('-'));
    }else if (tablero[i][j]==4){
     (tablero[i][j])=((char)('.'));
    }else if (tablero[i][j]==5){
     (tablero[i][j])=((char)('$'));
   
    }System.out.print (tablero[i][j]);
   }System.out.println("");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes declarado un vector con los símbolos que quieres imprimir, sólo tienes que utilizar el valor de la matriz como índice del vector a la hora de imprimir por pantalla:

```
public static void cambiaSim (int tablero[][]){
    char[] simbolos={'@','?','#','*','~','.','ç','/','$'};

    for (int i=0;i<tablero.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<tablero[0].length;j++){
            System.out.println(simbolos[(tablero[i][j])%9]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

Utilizo %. Esta operación se llama módulo y devuelve el resto de dividir un número entre otro. Yo hago %9 para que el resultado sea menor que 9 (que es la longitud del vector de símbolos), así a la hora de buscar una posición en el vector de símbolos no nos vamos a salir de él.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Pablo, problema solucionado (la solución la tenía ahí, era simple, pero no había dado con ella y había intentado de todo...) Muchísimas gracias

Comment: eso es, ya casi lo tenías. Ánimo!